# Why am I getting this error message unused arguments?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I know I'm doing something stupid, but I keep getting an error message when I try to use rename to rename columns in a data frame:

```
CENTERTBI_final <-rename(CENTERTBI_final, subjectId = Data_final.subjectId, Age= Data_final.Age, GCS = Data_final.InjuryHx.GCSScoreBaselineDerived, GCSMotor = Data_final.GCSMotor, GCSPupils = Data_final.GCSPupils, Glucose = Data_final.Labs.DLGlucosemmolL, Hemoglobin = Data_final.Labs.DLHemoglobingdL, Hypoxia = Data_final.Hypoxia, Hypotension = Data_final.Hypotension, MarshallCT = Data_final.MarshallCT, MarshallCT.v2 = Data_final.Imaging.MarshallCT.v2, SAH = Data_final.SAH, EDH = Data_final.EDH, GOSE_6mo = Data_final.Subject.GOSE6monthEndpointDerived)
```

The error I get is:

> Error in rename(CENTERTBI_final, subjectId = Data_final.subjectId, Age = Data_final.Age,  :
> unused arguments (subjectId = Data_final.subjectId, Age = Data_final.Age, GCS = Data_final.InjuryHx.GCSScoreBaselineDerived, GCSMotor = Data_final.GCSMotor, GCSPupils = Data_final.GCSPupils, Glucose = Data_final.Labs.DLGlucosemmolL, Hemoglobin = Data_final.Labs.DLHemoglobingdL, Hypoxia = Data_final.Hypoxia, Hypotension = Data_final.Hypotension, MarshallCT = Data_final.MarshallCT, MarshallCT.v2 = Data_final.Imaging.MarshallCT.v2, SAH = Data_final.SAH, EDH = Data_final.EDH, GOSE_6mo = Data_final.Subject.GOSE6monthEndpointDerived)

For reference, my column names are:

```
    > names(CENTERTBI_final)
```

[1] "Data_final.subjectId"                         "Data_final.Age"
[3] "Data_final.InjuryHx.GCSScoreBaselineDerived"  "Data_final.GCSMotor"
[5] "Data_final.GCSPupils"                         "Data_final.Labs.DLGlucosemmolL"
[7] "Data_final.Labs.DLHemoglobingdL"              "Data_final.Hypotension"
[9] "Data_final.Hypoxia"                           "Data_final.MarshallCT"
[11] "Data_final.Imaging.MarshallCT.v2"             "Data_final.SAH"
[13] "Data_final.EDH"                               "Data_final.Subject.GOSE6monthEndpointDerived"

Comment: try `dplyr::rename(...)`. (This is probably a duplicate ...)

Comment: Yes! I was the victim of masking. Thank you!